# ScrollView using storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm new to swift programming and storyboard usage. I want to know if it is possible to place my views inside a ScrollView using Storyboard and AutoLayout but visually. I'm not an expert so programming the constraints is a little hard for me now.

If it's possible can someone point me to a good starting point using xCode 6+. I'm planning to use iOS8+ as a requirement.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty easy!

I've written a tutorial that explain how to use UIScrollView with Auto Layout in iOS 8 and Swift.

Take a look, hopefully will help you :).
https://www.dribba.com/blog/2015/07/21/scrollview-autolayout-ios8-swift/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. I do it all the time in my current projects.

Just make sure you connect (auto layout constraints) your scrollable contents to all sides of the scrollview, so that it can calculate the content size correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Autolayout + UIScrollView is not a simple topic. Apple has a technical note on it:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html

I found these tutorials useful:

http://natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/
http://mobileoop.com/auto-layout-advanced-techniques-for-ios-8-and-7-using-xcode-6-on-storyboard
http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/?utm_source=maniacdev-ao&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=uiscrollview-autolayout-ios